# Is there something similer to shortcode in Joomla! & Magento

Tags: wordpress, magento, joomla, shortcode

I recently wrote a plugin to WordPress that inserts an Iframe according to a shortcode.
For example:

```
[PayButton width="900" total="200" height="500"]
```

My php code will call the appropriate function for the "PayButton" shortcode and replace it with the output.

Is there anything that works the same way in Joomla! and Magento? Im looking for a solution that exists in the core of Joomla! and Magento, and not as an extension.

Comment: If you're willing to integrate third party code, my library could come in handy: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Please take a look, I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a [widget system](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/banners-anywhere-with-magento-widget-instances/) that fills this purpose. You can use the built-in widgets that are already defined, or if you need to get more fancy you can create an extension that defines new widget types.